# unknown database connector error in my code

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

```
Dim rp As New ReportDocument
Dim myData As New MyDataSet
Dim dt As New MyDataSet.UserDataTable
Dim FirstRow As MyDataSet.UserRow = _
  CType(myData.User.NewRow, MyDataSet.UserRow)
FirstRow.MemberID = "1"
FirstRow.FirstName = "Amir Hossein"
FirstRow.LastName = "Rahnama"
myData.User.Rows.Add(FirstRow)

Dim SecondRow As MyDataSet.UserRow = _
  CType(myData.User.NewRow, MyDataSet.UserRow)
SecondRow.MemberID = "2"
SecondRow.FirstName = "Aziz"
SecondRow.LastName = "Khodaie"
myData.User.Rows.Add(SecondRow)

rp.Load("C:\Report.rpt")
rp.SetDataSource(myData)
CRV1.ReportSource = rp
```

When setting the datasource It comes up with an error:

> Unknown Database Connector Error
>   Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\A_RAHN~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\Report {832105B2-2E31-4018-9761-77581CC86142}.rpt:
>   Unknown Database Connector Error

To let you know, I created that report by Crystal Reports 2008 Stand-alone IDE rather than generating it in VS2010 IDE and it is binded to that dataset dutring the crystal report wizard.

Comment: Man I hate Crystal Reports...good luck :)

Comment: What happens if you bring the report into the VS2010 project, and instead of using `rp.Load` you `Dim rp As New MyReport`?  You may get a more useful error.

Comment: I cannot because we do not have it right now and I am dead if i can not fix it now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is that you will add an attribute to startup element in the following order:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">        
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: Only part of this that it took me a minute to figure out is where to put this.  Figured out that it was in the app.config of the executable that I run.  My Crystal stuff is in a DLL that is referenced from multiple EXEs and the ones that were written in C++ were working fine.

Answer (score -1):

If this error occur in Crystal Reports then you need to Install crystal report where this error occur.

Then make connection than you have use at development time it will give to original error detail that is cause of this error.